# How do I non-recursively gather folder sizes and their names? (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, directory, filesystemobject, non-recursive

Basically what I'm trying to do is gather users folder size from their network folder then export that to a .csv, directory structure looks something like this: network:\Department\user...User's-stuff

The script I have right now gets the department file name and the user's folder size, but not the user's name (folder name in the department). As for the TimeStamp, I'm not sure it's working correctly. It's meant to make a timestamp when it starts on the users in the next department so basically, all users in the same department will have the same timestamp.

This is what I have so far:

```
$root = "network"
$container= @()
$place = "C:\temp\"
$file = "DirectoryReport.csv"

Function Get-FolderSize
{

    BEGIN{$fso = New-Object -comobject Scripting.FileSystemObject}

    PROCESS
        {
        $prevDept = (Split-Path $path -leaf)

        $path = $input.fullname

        $folder = $fso.GetFolder($path)

        $Volume = $prevDept + "-users"

        $user = $folder.name #can't figure this part out...

        $size = $folder."size(MB)"

        if ( (Split-Path $path -leaf) -ne $prevDept)
        {
            $time = Get-Date -format M/d/yyy" "HH:mm #Probably wrong too..
        } 

        return $current = [PSCustomObject]@{'Path' = $path; 'Users' = $user; 'Size(MB)' = ($size /1MB ); 'Volume' = $Volume; 'TimeStamp' = $time;} 

        }

} 

$container += gci $root -Force -Directory -EA 0 | Get-FolderSize

$container

#Creating the .csv path

$placeCSV = $place + $file

#Checks if the file already exists
if ((test-path ($placeCSV)) -eq $true)
    {
       $file = "DirectoryReport" + [string](Get-Date -format MM.d.yyy.@h.mm.sstt) + ".csv" 
       rename-item -path $placeCSV -newname $file
       $placeCSV = $place + $file
    }

#Exports the CSV file to desired folder

$container | epcsv $placeCSV -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

But in the CSV file the user and the timestamp are wrong. Thanks for any/all help

Comment: This shouldn't work in general... the Size attribute on folders retrieved this way ends up Null. When you say non-recursively, do you not want to include the contents of subfolders in your size? You don't want total size, just the combined size of the files in the root folder?

Comment: No I mean I just don't want to have to sum up each subfolder inside of the users folder. I was hoping to retrieve the folder size it's self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really seems to be doing it the hard way. Why you wouldn't just use Get-ChildItem to do this almost makes this script seem a little masochistic to me, so I'm going to use that cmdlet instead of creating a comobject to do it.

I am a little confused as to why you wouldn't want to recurse for size, but ok, we'll go that route. This will get you your folders sizes, in MB.

```
#Get a listing of department folders
$Depts = GCI $root -force -Directory

#Loop through them
ForEach($Dept in $Depts){
    $Users = @()
    $Timestamp = Get-Date -Format "M/d/yyy HH:mm"

    #Loop through each user for the current department
    GCI $Dept -Directory |%{
        $Users += [PSCustomObject]@{
            User=$_.Name
            Path=$_.FullName
            "Size(MB)"=(GCI $_|Measure-Object -Sum Length|Select Sum)/1MB
            Volume="$($Dept.Name)-Users"
            TimeStamp=$Timestamp
        }
    }
}

#Rename output file if it exists
If(Test-Path "C:\Temp\DirectoryReport.csv"){
    Rename-Item "C:\Temp\DirectoryReport.csv" "DirectoryReport.$(Get-Date -format MM.d.yyy.@h.mm.sstt).csv"
}

#Output file
$Users | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\DirectoryReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to get the total size for all files within each user's folder, including files within subfolders, change the `"Size(MB)"=(GCI $_|Measure-Object -Sum Length|Select Sum)/1MB` to be recursive by replacing it with `"Size(MB)"=(GCI $_ -recurse|Measure-Object -Sum Length|Select Sum)/1MB` and that should have you good to go.

Comment: My supervisor doesn't want to do it recursively. Even I think doing this non-recursively is pretty redundant.. Thanks for the help I'll try it and get back to you!